# Unable to link to quantlib

Tags: c++, gcc, quantlib

I'm trying to learn QuantLib, this is my first program with which i intend to check that my environment is ok and i'm able to link to quantlib:

```
#include <ql/time/all.hpp>

using namespace QuantLib;

int main ()
{
  Date d1(14, February, 2014);
  return 0;
}
```

I've got my quantlib libraries installed under /usr/local/lib, headers under /usr/local/include/ql. I try to compile this little program with:

```
$ LC_ALL=C g++ -Wall -lQuantLib -o sample1 quantlib-sample-1.cpp
/tmp/cc4Z2xsf.o: In function `main':
quantlib-sample-1.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `QuantLib::Date::Date(int, QuantLib::Month, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The thing gets worse if i include "ql/quantlib.hpp" (much more errors like the one above). I tried passing "-L/usr/local/lib" for if my ldconfig is not ok.

I'm a bit lost here... Any clue?

Comment: Try building the examples included with QuantLib and see if they build.

Comment: Yes, when i built Quantlib all the examples compiled ok. Examples use static linking, so i've tried '-static' also. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Also tried to setup all flags returned by 'quantlib-config'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command used to compile is malformed. Library linking options need to go after outputs and inputs. This works:

```
$ LC_ALL=C g++ -Wall -o sample1 quantlib-sample-1.cpp -lQuantLib
```

With '-lQuantLib' at the end of the command.

It works both including 'ql/quantlib.hpp' or 'ql/time/all.hpp'.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I change the first line to the more general (and recommended) catch-all include:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -o qldate qldate.cpp -lQuantLib    ## no errors or warnings
edd@max:/tmp$ cat qldate.cpp 
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>

using namespace QuantLib;

int main ()
{
  Date d1(14, February, 2014);
  return 0;
}
edd@max:/tmp$
```

Comment: This does not work for me. As i told in the question the thing gets worse (a lot of "Undefined reference" linker errors).

Comment: Well that is then no longer reproducible. Also, you said that you *can* build the example so you may want to compare more closely what they do relative to what you do.  You had one error which I fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Let me make it work and test that it does not compile with "ql/time/all.hpp", after that i'll mark this correct if that's the case.

Comment: I've posted my own answer, the problem was with compilation flags order. It works including 'ql/time/all.hpp'. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Confirmed.  I had a -l/-L typo. So it was command-order, and I showed you that too ;-)